# Vaadin 7 and org.vaadin.addon.customfield. package

Tags: java, vaadin, custom-fields, vaadin7

I have to upgrade an application from vaadin6 to vaadin7. 
I have a problem in two classes:

```
import org.vaadin.addon.customfield.CustomField;
public abstract class DictionaryItemValuesField  extends CustomField{
```

and

```
import org.vaadin.addon.customfield.FieldWrapper;
public abstract class DateFieldWithTextField<DF extends DateField> extends FieldWrapper<Date> {
```

org.vaadin.addon.customfield(v1.0.0) is vaadin6 package, it uses vaacin6 packages like com.vaadin.terminal. So this package isn't supported by vaadin7. 
So how can I migrate those two classes to vaadin7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CustomField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/CustomField.html) is now part of Vaadin7 base API.

> It is also possible to override validate(), setInternalValue(), commit(), setPropertyDataSource, isEmpty() and other methods to implement different functionalities in the field. Methods overriding setInternalValue() should call the superclass method.

Comment: I don't think that it's supported by vaadin7:

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/customfield

Comment: Yes, you can not longer use this addon with Vaadin7.  It is integrated into the base Vaadin7 API.

Comment: Thank you but when I used com.vaadin.ui.CustomField instead of org.vaadin.addon.customfield.CustomField I found a problem for setWriteThrough() and setCompositionRoot() doesn't exist in com.vaadin.ui.CustomField what do you propose

Comment: I am not sure, what `setWriteThrough` is supposed to do - but it sounds alot like `setBuffered`.  For the `setCompositionRoot` https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/CustomField.html#initContent%28%29 is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you have an idea about FieldWrapper in vaadin7?

Comment: as far as i know, there is no replacement for FieldWrapper.  You could write your own, based on the original code of the FieldWrapper.  But as you can see in the FieldWrapper, you will have to pass down alot of funktionality.  You might even be better off to just subclass the wrapped field class itself.